# how to translate object to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I got from web api `[{"id":45,"username":"xx@xxxx.xx"}]` the list of objects, actually I know for sure, that always there will be only one item in the list (like in example above), how could I translate this string to the array, to get the information by arr['id']

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = json_decode('[{"id":45,"username":"xx@xxxx.xx"}]') ;
print_r($var) ;
```

Comment: I tried it, after I use file_put_contents('check.txt', PHP_EOL . print_r($var), FILE_APPEND); to writes the results in file, and it shows "1".... don't you know why?

Comment: print_r make a print and return 1 when finished. If you want print_r to return the value you need print_r($var,true) instead of print_r($var) ;

Comment: @SergeyVladimirovich Try this :
`<?php
$objects = json_decode('[{"id":45,"username":"xx@xxxx.xx"}]',true);
$finalResult = (Array)$objects[0];
foreach($finalResult as $key => $val){
    echo $key. ' = ' . $val.'<br />';
}
?>`